# Angular Lazy loading not Navigating

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm want to implement Angular lazing loading in my app.

I read through so many books and it seems this the normal way to do it, maybe I missed something important and it's been two days.

https://github.com/kondasMajid/angula-lazy-loading

App-routing-Module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'view',
    loadChildren: 'app/view/view.module#ViewModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<button routerLink="/view">view</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

view.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ViewRoutingModule } from './view-routing.module';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewComponent } from './view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ViewComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ViewRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class ViewModule { }
```

view.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'view',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.css']
}) 
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: view.component.ts

`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'view',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.css']
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot of problems with your current implementation:

1. You've used `forChild` instead of `forRoot` in your AppRoutingModule.
2. In your `ViewModule` you're doing I don't know what. Ideally, your `Routes` should be defined in a ViewRoutingModule and then the `RouterModule` should be exported from there and imported in your ViewModule.
3. The empty route(`''`) in your AppRoutingModule's `Routes` config might end up being an infinite loop. So you might want to redirect to somewhere else in that case.

Fixing these two issues should make it work:

**AppRoutingModule**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'view',
    loadChildren: 'app/view/view.module#ViewModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**ViewRoutingModule**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ViewComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class ViewRoutingModule { }
```

**ViewModule**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ViewRoutingModule } from './view-routing.module';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ViewComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ViewRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class ViewModule { }
```

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uri-encode-activated-route-param?file=src%2Fapp%2Fview%2Fview.module.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i did what you just said, yet i'm not able to navigate to the page.

Comment: @KondasLamarJnr, I've updated my answer. There was another issue with your `ViewModule`. Hopefully, my updated answer should fix your issues.

Comment: thanks alot, but definetly not going well enough for my so i have created a repo on Github , kidly check out for me..  https://github.com/kondasMajid/angula-lazy-loading

Comment: Your GitHub repo doesn't have the view Folder and the home folder. How do you expect it to work?

Comment: ooh. i don't really know whats going on. i can see the folder in my Vscode with the codes. i'm now confuse as well.

Comment: pls check the repo now, was a github issue.
the view and home folders are there. thanks :) 

@SiddAjmera

Comment: There's something wrong with your branch itself. I fixed almost all the issues but I'm still getting an error saying **Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Location: (?).**

Comment: Please consider using this StackBlitz link to clearly understand: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcrhf4

Comment: Thanks very much i will follow up with your link to stackblitz

Comment: Hi there @SiddAjmera.
I'm able to work on it now and i think i have learn't a lot now. 
Really appreciate your effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `app.routing.ts` should read like this that will be the first change

`imports[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],`

Second change is that you need to `redirectTo` correct path when your route is empty

Try something like this

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/view',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

Hope these changes will work - happy coding :)

**Update:**

I think you missed a major missing here - I don't see your `AppRoutingModule` imported inside your `AppModule`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule //This will do the trick
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Try the above changes and import your routing inside your module - Hope it works

Comment: I have checked your repo :) i have updated my answer try it and let me know :)